# React router V6 vs V5 - login?redirect=my_other_page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In react router V5, you can use

`history.push('/login?redirect=other_page')`

to redirect a user either to `'/login'`, or to `'/other_page'` (if already logged in )

What is the equivalent in react router V6 with useNavigate ?

`navigate('/login?redirect=other_page')`

doesn't work as intended.

When the user is logged-in, it returns the path `'/login/other_page'` instead of `'/other_page'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-router-dom` v6 uses absolute ***and*** relative navigation. My guess is that with path `'/login?redirect=other_page'` the `redirect` queryString value is `"other_page"` and you are redirecting there *from* `"/login"`, i.e. relative from `"/login"` to `"/login/other_path"`. The difference between absolute and relative navigation is the leading `"/"` character. Absolute paths start with `"/"` while relative paths do not.

You could try sending an absolute path `'/login?redirect=/other_page'`.

```
navigate('/login?redirect=/other_page');
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-vs-v5-loginredirect-my-other-page]